# XamlObjectWriterException при попытке отобразить страницу

Tags: wpf, .net

При попытке отобразить страницу во Frame выскакивает исключение 
"WpfApp1.PageContent" не соответствует фактическому типу корневого экземпляра "System.Windows.Controls.Page". Удалите директиву Class или предоставьте экземпляр с помощью свойства XamlObjectWriterSettings.RootObjectInstance.
Что это может означать?

В окне:

```
<Frame Name="frame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
Source="C:\repos\WpfApp1\WpfApp1\Page1.xaml"/>
```

Страница:

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApp1.Page1"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
          mc:Ignorable="d" 
          d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
          Title="Page1">

        <Grid>
            <Border Background="Aqua"/>
            <TextBlock>weqweqweqwewrewr</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Page>
```

Comment: Добавьте код на котором воспроизводится проблема

Comment: @АндрейNOP, добавил

Comment: А если указать путь просто: `Source="Page1.xaml"`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, то пустой экран. Ошибок нет, но и страницы тоже нет